# TLS 1.3 handshake Failure - Client reports "Header Too Long"

Tags: ssl, openssl, client-side, tls1.3

I'm in process of updating the client to support TLS 1.3. When trying to connect to TLS 1.3 server, client is reporting "Internal error". Wireshark traces showing that server responded with `Verify Certificate, Finished` message. But client fails to generate the keys with following call stack -

```
 libcrypto-1_1.dll!ASN1_get_object(const unsigned char * * pp, long * plength, int * ptag, int * pclass, long omax) Line 101
 libcrypto-1_1.dll!asn1_item_embed_d2i(ASN1_VALUE_st * * pval, const unsigned char * * in, long len, const ASN1_ITEM_st * it, int tag, int aclass, char opt, ASN1_TLC_st * ctx, int depth) Line 287
 [Inline Frame] libcrypto-1_1.dll!ASN1_item_ex_d2i(ASN1_VALUE_st * *) Line 124
 libcrypto-1_1.dll!ASN1_item_d2i(ASN1_VALUE_st * * pval, const unsigned char * * in, long len, const ASN1_ITEM_st * it) Line 114
 libcrypto-1_1.dll!d2i_X509_SIG(X509_sig_st * * a, const unsigned char * * in, long len) Line 21    
 MyCode.dll!PrivateKeyOperationCallback(ssl_st * pSSL, unsigned int type, unsigned int rsakeysize, const unsigned char * hash, unsigned int hashlen, unsigned char * sig, unsigned int sigmaxlen, unsigned int * siglen)
 [Inline Frame] MyCode.dll!My_RSA_private_encrypt1(ssl_st *)
 MyCode.dll!My_RSA_private_encrypt(int flen, const unsigned char * from, unsigned char * to, rsa_st * rsa, int padding)
 libcrypto-1_1.dll!pkey_rsa_sign(evp_pkey_ctx_st * ctx, unsigned char * sig, unsigned int * siglen, const unsigned char * tbs, unsigned int tbslen) Line 185
 libcrypto-1_1.dll!EVP_PKEY_sign(evp_pkey_ctx_st * ctx, unsigned char * sig, unsigned int * siglen, const unsigned char * tbs, unsigned int tbslen) Line 66
 libcrypto-1_1.dll!EVP_DigestSignFinal(evp_md_ctx_st * ctx, unsigned char * sigret, unsigned int * siglen) Line 148
 libcrypto-1_1.dll!EVP_DigestSign(evp_md_ctx_st * ctx, unsigned char * sigret, unsigned int * siglen, const unsigned char * tbs, unsigned int tbslen) Line 170
 libssl-1_1.dll!tls_construct_cert_verify(ssl_st * s, wpacket_st * pkt) Line 307
 libssl-1_1.dll!write_state_machine(ssl_st * s) Line 843
 libssl-1_1.dll!state_machine(ssl_st * s, int server) Line 443
 libssl-1_1.dll!ossl_statem_connect(ssl_st * s) Line 250
 libssl-1_1.dll!SSL_do_handshake(ssl_st * s) Line 3661
 libssl-1_1.dll!SSL_connect(ssl_st * s) Line 1662
```

ASN1_get_object returns "Header Too Long". Same client is able to connect to same server with TLS 1.2 and even able to connect to same server from browser with TLS 1.3.

Issue is specifically with mTLS (not with TLS).

Comment: You say same code fails on 1.3 AND is able to connect with 1.3. Did you really mean something else, like 1.2?

Comment: Typo. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

That code path is not unique to TLS 1.3, and has been present in OpenSSL / libcrypto for quite a long time.

The error is occurring because an ASN.1 object encoded in the certificate has a definite length that exceeds the length of the data provided. Either the certificate data is corrupt, or the server is not sending the correct data.

If you're implementing the TLS 1.3 client yourself it is possible that your code is not properly handling certificate encryption, leading to garbled data being sent into the ASN.1 parsing code paths. Without further information (Wireshark dumps and the certificate itself) it is impossible to know what the specific error is.

Comment: What certificate encryption? Do you mean constructing the digital signature?

Comment: TLS 1.3 encrypts everything after the ServerHello. This includes the certificate. The behaviour is described in [RFC8446](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446).

Comment: I see no evidence of any certificate here. 'MyCode.dll' is being called to do RSA _signing_ (which OpenSSL for hysterical raisins sometimes calls RSA_private_encrypt) and for some reason calls `d2i_X509_SIG` which would parse a DigestInfo (not a whole cert) and I see no sane reason RSA signing should ever parse a DigestInfo -- unless maybe it's getting the privatekey from a PKCS12 with a MAC. I would look at the code in 'MyCode.dll'.

Comment: At high-level sequence is same but TLS 1.3 code is different at couple of places like get_cert_verify_tbs_data and couple of other places. Since browser is able to connect to same server with TLS 1.3 so there are less chances that server is sending corrupted or incorrect data. Even if server is sending incorrect data then browser is handling that well.